# I want to plot a rectangle with given 4 coordinates in a text file in gnuplot. The rectangle may be at an angle to x axis

Tags: python, random, plot, gnuplot, rectangles

How do I read the data from the file and plot the rectangle?
The given text file has the following format up to 50 rows: 
x1  y1  x2  y2  x3  y3  x4  y4

where (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3) and (x4,y4) are the four vertices of the rectangle. The rectangles have random orientation. How do I plot the series of rectangles in gnuplot?

If someone can tell me how to read from a file while using set object polygon, that may also be helpful
what I want: set object polygon from  to  to  to .

Or, is there any other simpler code in gnuplot? Alternatively is there a python solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My `Gnuplot` solution (not just for rectangles, but any kind of polygons):

```
plot 'rectal.dat' u 1:2:($3-$1):($4-$2) with vectors nohead lc 1 title 'Rectangle', \
'' u 3:4:($5-$3):($6-$4) with vectors nohead lc 1 notitle,  \
'' u 5:6:($7-$5):($8-$6) with vectors nohead lc 1 notitle, \ 
'' u 7:8:($1-$7):($2-$8) with vectors nohead lc 1 notitle
```

---

[image]
from

> 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0
>
> 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 0
>
> -0.5 -0.5 -1 1 -0.5 2 0 1

Answer (score 1):

Here's the Python code to do so as we discussed.

Your input file is of format:

```
__ __ x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3 x4 y4
```

The code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.loadtxt('car.txt')
data = [i[2:] for i in data]
for d in data:
    Xs = d[::2]
    Ys = d[1::2]
    for i in range(4):
        if i < 3:
            plt.plot([Xs[i],Xs[i+1]],[Ys[i],Ys[i+1]],'k-',lw=2)
        elif i == 3:
            plt.plot([Xs[i],Xs[0]],[Ys[i],Ys[0]],'k-',lw=2)

plt.show()
```